# Anyway to suppress play and/or it's task output when it's ignored via a when clause?

Tags: ansible

Here is my playbook (trimmed greatly for brevity):

```
- name: "__PERFORMING_PREFLIGHT_CHECKS__"
  hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  run_once: true
  roles:
    - { role: roles/inventory-check, delegate_to: localhost, delegate_facts: true }
    - { role: roles/registering-facts }
    - { role: roles/verify-certificates, when: ssl.enable | d(false) | bool == true  }

- name: "__DEPLOYING_CLUSTER_CERTIFICATES__"
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  roles:
    - { role: roles/cluster-certificates, when: ssl.enable | d(false) | bool == true }
```

When ssl.enable == false, it doesn't execute the tasks but I see a section in the output:

```
PLAY [__DEPLOYING_CLUSTER_CERTIFICATES__] 

TASK [roles/cluster-certificates : Setting variable cluster_ssl_dir=/minIO/data/.ssl] ******************************************************************************************
Wednesday 06 May 2020  12:00:07 -0700 (0:00:00.051)       0:00:48.417 *********

TASK [roles/cluster-certificates : Creating cluster certificate directories '{{ cluster_ssl_dir }}'] ******************************************************************************************
Wednesday 06 May 2020  12:00:08 -0700 (0:00:00.130)       0:00:48.548 *********

TASK [roles/cluster-certificates : Pushing cluster certificates] ******************************************************************************************
Wednesday 06 May 2020  12:00:08 -0700 (0:00:00.129)       0:00:48.677 *********
```

Anyway to suppress this?

It would be one thing if it was useful output saying "this was ignored beause blah", but it doesn't even say that much. It's confusing and it makes people unfamiliar with your automation think something is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to remove skipped tasks at the playbook, role or task level. It can be done by modifying the default callback plugin however.

In [ansible.cfg](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#envvar-ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_SKIPPED_HOSTS) add the following:

`display_skipped_hosts = False`

Here's a before and after with 2.9.6. Note the two skipped tasks:

```
PLAY [test] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [include a role] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test_role : set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test_role : stat] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [test_role : debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And after. The summary still mentions the skipped tasks:

```
PLAY [test] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test_role : set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You may also come across other options such as `stdout_callback = skippy`. These have be deprecated however.